# Run-Time error '3048' happening even though I close connections

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

I've been getting an error that I've never seen before. I keep seeing this:

> Run-time error '3048':
>
> Cannot open any more databases.

Having Googled it, it seems this happens when there are very complicated forms that have lots of lists or combo boxes that have their sources as a table/query. However, I've not changed these forms for a while now and I'm all of a sudden seeing this. Plus, my forms really aren't that complicated, usually just a single list and maybe 1 or 2 combo boxes. I just started seeing this error yesterday (2/2/22)

Almost in all cases I'm accessing the tables by using this code:

```
Dim rst As Recordset: Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("table name or SQL statement")
```

Then I'll access data using something like, whether it be AddNew, Edit, or just looping through a recordset.

```
With rst
    .AddNew
    .Fields("name") = "Value"
End With
```

OR

```
Do Until rst.EOF
    'Do something
    .MoveNext
Loop
```

And I've already double checked that every time I open a recordset I close it

```
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

However, I keep seeing that error now. Is there some other way that I'm supposed to close these recordsets that properly closes the connection? I'm guessing opening these is causing something to linger that I'm not aware of.

the only solution I have right now is to completely restart my PC and then I can use it for a bit before I see the error again.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: When I get that error, I can't even close everything in Access and manually open a table to look at it. I get this error message

> Reserved error (-1104); there is no message for this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, sadly, a known current bug:

[Access doesn't close properly. A remaining background process can only be terminated in task manager](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/access/access-doesn-t-close-properly-a-remaining-background-process-can/m-p/3103807)

There is no official info or remedy yet.

Comment: Thanks, I ended finding access running in the background when I kept getting messages that files were opened by myself. Thats at least easier than completely restarting my pc.

Comment: If this is the case, maybe you could try to find the [PID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075292/determine-process-id-with-vba) of other access instances, then [kill those process](https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/cu1n95/close_application_based_on_pid/)

Comment: For me, I'm only able to see that background MS Access once I've closed the one that is throwing the error. This must be a new issue that just cropped up with a recent update.

Comment: @JasonBrady: It is. Also, see [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/access/access-doesn-t-close-properly-a-remaining-background-process-can/m-p/3103807).

Comment: @Gustav: Your link to the page of reverting Office 365 to the previous version helped me in this problem.

Comment: The issue should have been solved with the current update to _Version 2201 (Build 14827.20192 Click-to-run)_.

Answer (score 0):

I also got these problems after updating Office 365 tot the latest version (221, build 14827.20158). When I close the Access application and reopen it, I immediately get the error. Then I first have to resatart my computer in order to have the application working until it reaches the max amount of conections.

Comment: The links provided in the other answer are really good, but short and sweet, if you shut down Access, open task manager, you'll find a Microsoft Access process under Background processes. End that task and then you can open Access and use it normally until you run out of TableIDs. Then you just rinse and repeat.

Comment: I reverted my version of Office 365 to the previous version as Gustav recommended in the previous answer. Now I can use Access as normal.

Comment: Mine is a work computer and convincing IT to do that for me will be tricky. I'll probably just wait it out.

Comment: Mine is a work computer too and I solved it together with our IT managing company. They showed me how to revert Office and afterwards I managed to revert all Office versions on the other computers of our company using Access.

Answer (score 0):

When opening a database of an earlier version (.mdb format) in Microsoft Access version 2013 or later, you may encounter an error ‘Cannot open a database created with a previous version of your application.’

You can fix the error by converting the old database file format (.mdb) to the .accdb file format.

To work around this, Microsoft recommends opening the Access database (MDB) in Access 2007 or later versions, and then saving it in the file format you can open in Access version 2013 or higher.

Follow the below link to perform the steps to convert the .mdb file to .accdb file format:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/convert-a-database-to-the-accdb-file-format-098ddd31-5f84-4e89-8f44-db0cf7c11acd#

Best Regards,

Alice