# I need Excel VBA to wait until Qlikview finishes working

Tags: excel, vba, qlikview

First question I leave here, so I hope it is correct.

My problem seems to be simple: I want to know the best way to keep excel waiting until another application (Qlikview) is done loading graphics and tables.

I have a code that controls what Qlikview does outside Qlikviews script, and works fine, but my problem is that sometimes after a certain order Qklikview takes some time to reload, and excel continues before this loading is finished.

I leave here an example of this code I'm using:

```
Set f = QvDoc.Fields("Tarifa")
    f.Select "(0)"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    Set f = QvDoc.Fields("nom_mar")
    f.Select Mar
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    
    'Set the path where the excel will be saved
    SA = Ruta & ".xls"
    CD2 = CP & SA
    'Create the Excel spreadsheet
    Set ExcelFile = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ExcelFile.Visible = True
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    'Create the WorkBook
    Set curWorkbook = ExcelFile.Workbooks.Add
    'Create the Sheet
    Set curSheet = curWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    'Get the chart we want to export
    Set tableToExport = QvDoc.GetSheetObject("CH444")
    Set ChartProperties = tableToExport.GetProperties
    tableToExport.CopyTableToClipboard True
    'Get the caption
    chartCaption = tableToExport.GetCaption.Name.v
'    MsgBox chartCaption
    'Set the first cell with the caption
    curSheet.Range("A1") = chartCaption
    'Paste the rest of the chart
    curSheet.Paste curSheet.Range("A2")
    ExcelFile.Visible = True
    'Save the file and quit excel
    curWorkbook.SaveAs CD2
    curWorkbook.Close
    ExcelFile.Quit
    'Cleanup
    Set curWorkbook = Nothing
    Set ExcelFile = Nothing
'    Set XLApp = Nothing
```

I've done quite a bit of searching, and the best I've found was the "Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))" trick.

The problem is that sometimes, the loading last for more than 2 seconds. I guess that adding more seconds to "Application.Wait" would solve this problem, but I would like to know a more sofisticated way, maybe a loop with the method "sleep" that makes excel wait untin Qlikview has finished

I've tried using "qvDoc.GetApplication.WaitForIdle 1000" after some research (see [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)), but it doesn't work.

Can anybody help me? I would be more than happy to give more info about this if needed.

Best regards,

Mike

Comment: You may want to review: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49389094/3688861

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74387976/12287457

Comment: I wasn't able to find those in my research. I'll save them, as they have a lot of info.

The first comentary with the "doevents" method seems to work, while the other one is a complete guide for this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the process ID [vba get process id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075292/determine-process-id-with-vba) and make a cycle while there is a process.