# Refreshing queries in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

long time reader, first time asker,

I have a master file that when i hit a button will Open 11 files one by one refresh the connections and close the files. however, it's not refreshing the connections before it closes the file.

```
Sub Task()

Workbooks.Open Filename:= "......sharepoint.com/sites/dummylocation/dummyfile.xlsx"

Dim WB As Workbook

Set WB = Application.Workbooks("dummy file.xlsx")
Dim ObjConnection As Variant
Dim bBackground As Variant

For Each ObjConnection In WB.Connections
'Get current background-refresh value
bBackground = ObjConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery
'Temporarily disable background-refresh
ObjConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
'Refresh this connection
ObjConnection.Refresh
'Set background-refresh value back to original value
ObjConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = bBackground
Next
WB.Close
End Sub
```

Ive been able to fault find it a little bit by commenting out the "wb.cose" which the Refresh then works.
Im assuming i need some kind of delay or something?????

Comment: Maybe a `DoEvents` or two might help

Comment: Perhaps `Application.Wait` as well as `DoEvents`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.wait

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I got multiple solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75094344/i-need-excel-vba-to-wait-until-qlikview-finishes-working)

What worked perfectly for me was adding a function like this:

```
Function WaitUntilFinish(Seconds As Double)
    Dim StopTime As Double: StopTime = Timer + Seconds
    Do While Timer < StopTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Function
```

And then using it in the code. May I suggest you use it here?

```
'Refresh this connection
ObjConnection.Refresh
WaitUntilFinish (Seconds)
'Set background-refresh value back to original value
ObjConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = bBackground
```